# Determine which connection to use

Tags: c#

In my code, if I have multiple connection string, how can I achieve that without create another ExecuteNonQuery() shared function because of the multiple connection? I thinking of using if else to determine whether a class function call ExecuteNonQuery() should use particular connection string for open/close connection, I want to reuse the ExecuteNonQuery() ever have different connection, any better idea? Or if the design are wrong?

```
public void OpenConnection()
{
    try
    {
        string strSQLSvr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnStr"].ConnectionString;
        string strUsrSvr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["usrMaint"].ConnectionString;

        conn = new SqlConnection(strSQLSvr);
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

public void CloseConnection()
{
    try {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

public void ExecuteNonQuery(string strSQL)
{
    try
    {
        OpenConnection();
        cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: I only see one connection in your code...

Comment: yes you have only one connection in your code where is another..

Comment: Use `using` statement. You *should* have to **avoid** rough code design.

Comment: Yes, the code I put only have 1 connection string, I thinking of adding another connection, how to do it? As the function are use by different class, I did look into "using", but still have no idea how can I reuse back my ExecuteNonQuery()? Any code sample for idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use of below design

```
public class DatabaseConnection 
{

    private static DbConnection createSQlConnectionWithDB1()
    {
        // create a connection with DB1

        return new SqlConnection();
    }

    private static DbConnection createSQlConnectionWithDB2()
    {
       // create a connection with DB2
        return new SqlConnection();
    }


    public  static DbConnection createConnection(string typeOfConnection)
    {
        if (typeOfConnection.Equals("DB1"))
            return createSQlConnectionWithDB1();

        if (typeOfConnection.Equals("DB2"))
            return createSQlConnectionWithDB2();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: so means that, I need to pass in the type of connection at different classes?

Comment: yup, that you need to pass , it just taking the responsibility from the class and delegate it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create different connection objects in your `OpenConnection()` function , according to connection string changes.

And then, you can simply pass the connection object to `ExecuteNonQuery` function.

This way it can be worked.